# Is it possible to complete all contracts in Assassins Creed Brotherhood?

Tags: assassins-creed-brotherhood

I have completed most of Assassins Creed Brotherhood, and now trying to send my assassins out on all the missions to complete all of the available missions. However, as the missions renew, is it possible to ever complete them all? Are they finite, or infinitely randomly generated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can't find the sources but from what i remember of my game play, the contracts with the diamonds are random and keep respawing, the ones with the circle actually have sort of a mini-story in the description and don't respawn.

So in essence you can't finish them all

Comment: Yes, my experience was that the contracts keep respawning.